# class object's declaration confucion

Tags: c++, class, object

```
whats is the difference between these three statements in c++ ??
aa *obj;   
aa *obj1 = new aa; 
aa *obj2 = new aa();
```

where aa is a class 
I am confucion in last two statement .

Comment: Two of them are explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Comment: He did say it was a class, not a built-in data type.  I guess it could be a POD, but that's really old compilers that care.

Comment: @JDługosz What matters is the language specification, not the compiler's age.

Comment: What do you mean?  Years ago, it worked one way. Now, *conforming* compilers work another way.  Spec or not, many of us had to cope with Visual Studio pre-7.1 when templates and such details did not work as specified.

Answer (score 1):

The first does not initialize the pointer.

In the latest specification,

> - If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed,
>     the object has indeterminate value.
> - Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct initialization.

That is, if the class (you said it was a class) doesn't *have* a constructor, then the first form will act the same as a local scope definition and leave the memory un-initialized.

The empty initializer will force it to be initialized anyway, which gives the same results as a *global* variable of that type.

A class might not have a constructor, even a hidden constructor, if it contains nothing but data members of primitive types.  You'll see that discussed as a "POD", or plain'ol data.  For templates, the difference was found to be annoying, so the rules were refined to work, with (), uniformly for any type, even built-in types.  `new int()` will give a pointer to a value holding 0.  `new int` will give a pointer to a value holding whatever garbage happened to be at that address before.

Comment: The second and third statements can differ in meaning depending on the definition of `aa`.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I knew it changed, but got that backwards. <sigh>.

Comment: Can anyone clarify on this      " the 1st statement [ aa *obj ] Will initialized pointer *obj automatically will address of class aa object . now the issue is - where's the object of aa is created and how its initialized implicit *obj pointer???  because i have just defined the pointer of class aa but not initialized it with aa address...????

Comment: `obj` is *not initialized* in the first statement. No object is created; nothing happens. Don't write that: declare the variable when you are ready to give it a value. Write `aa* obj= nullptr;` if you must leave it without a meaningful pointer.  Also, note that in C++, unlike C, the preferred style is to put the star with the type, not the variable.  Try the classic: Stroustrup's *The C++ Programming Language*.

Comment: The Question does not contain a program; just 3 variable declarations.